# Solving non coprime coefficient equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Suppose I have an equation $24\times a \equiv 12 \pmod {26}$. How do you solve this type of equation when the coefficient is not coprime with $26$?

Comment: Divide through by $2:$ $12a\equiv6\pmod{13}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
24a&\equiv12\pmod{26}\\
12a&\equiv6\pmod{13}\\
-a&\equiv6\pmod{13}\\
a&\equiv7\pmod{13}
\end{align}$$

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so it leaves the unsolved queue.

Comment: Lots of people don't, it seems.  It always bothers me when I look at a question and find it has a perfectly good answer that hasn't been accepted.